# Errors in for loop-Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, text-files

How can I find how many times power has been changed by more than 1W when the power was **on** from the below text file?

```
time power status
0 10 on
10 9.9 on
11 9.7 on
12 9 on
13 6 on
14 4 on
15 -1 off
20 10 on
25 9 on
26 5 on
27 4 on
28 -1 off
35 10 on
40 9 on
41 5 on
42 4 on
43 -1 off
```

I tried to run a **for** loop and could calculate how many times power changed when it was **on**. I'm having issues with how to calculate the difference between two consecutive data from the text file, in this case for power.
The final answer should be 4.

```
fid=fopen('power.txt');
line=fgetl(fid);
data=textscan(fid,'%d %f %s');
fclose(fid);

%data
time=data{1};
power=data{2};
status=data{3};


power_change1=0;
for n=1:length(time)
    power_change= abs(power(n)-power(n+1));
    if status(n)=="on" && power_change > 1
     power_change1=power_change1+1;

    end
    
end
power_change1
```

Comment: We can't fix your `for` loop if we can't see it. Please post your code.

Comment: I added my code. I think it's showing an error because of the last (n+1) when there are no more rows left but I can't figure out how to solve that.

Comment: The for-loop only needs to go up to `length(time)-1` since you'll have changes in between the time samples not for every single time sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method 1: Using a For-Loop

The for-loop only needs to go up to `length(time)-1` since you'll have changes in between the time samples not for every single time sample. Also, you need to check that both values used to evaluate the difference/change have a `status = "on"`.

```
fid=fopen('power.txt');
line=fgetl(fid);
data=textscan(fid,'%d %f %s');
fclose(fid);

%data
time=data{1};
power=data{2};
status=data{3};


Power_Change_Counter = 0;
for n=1:length(time)-1
    power_change= abs(power(n)-power(n+1));
    
    if status(n) == "on" && status(n+1) == "on" && power_change > 1
     Power_Change_Counter = Power_Change_Counter+1;
    end
    
end

Power_Change_Counter
```

---

### Method 2: Using `diff()` Function

Here I create an array representing the "ON" and "OFF" states using `contains()`. This array will be called `Binary_State` in this example and will be equal to `1` when the machine/device is "ON" and `NaN` when the machine/device is "OFF". Setting the `NaN` (Not a Number) terms is done through matrix-indexing. We can then multiply the `power` by the `Binary_State` element-wise to get a new array called `Power_When_On` that only holds that power values corresponding to when the machine/device is "ON". The rest of the values within the `Power_When_On` array are `NaN` (when the machine/device is "OFF"). Finally, the difference between the elements can be taken by using the `diff()` function to find the changes/transitions while the machine/device is "ON"/running. The last step is finding how many terms are greater than `1`. This can be done by evaluating when the absolute of the `Power_Changes` is greater than 1. The function `nnz()` is used to count how many true statements (number of non-zero) elements there are.

[image: Power Changes Array]

```
fid=fopen('power.txt');
line=fgetl(fid);
data=textscan(fid,'%d %f %s');
fclose(fid);

time = data{1};
power = data{2};
status = data{3};

Binary_State = contains(status,"on")';
Binary_State = double(Binary_State);
Binary_State(Binary_State == 0) = NaN;

Power_When_On = Binary_State.*power.';
Power_Changes = diff(Power_When_On);

Number_Of_Greater_Than_1W_Changes = nnz(abs(Power_Changes) > 1);
Number_Of_Greater_Than_1W_Changes
```

---

### Extension: For a Plot and More Insight:

The power changes between the timestamps during the "ON" periods can be plotted.

[image: Power Change Graph]

```
Mid_Time = zeros(1,length(time)-1);
for Index = 1: length(time)-1
    Mid_Time(1,Index) = (double(time(Index)) + double(time(Index + 1)))/2;
end 
    
stairs(Mid_Time,Power_Changes,'-o');
title("Power Changes Between Consecutive Times");
xlabel("Time"); ylabel("Power Change [W]");
xticks(0:max(Mid_Time));
grid;
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**